# How to create a file with a given size?

Tags: c

I want to create a file in C with a given file size. Is it possible?

Comment: What's wrong with the question?

Comment: The user did not describe what he tried, where he encountered difficulty, or the details of his problem.  Lots is wrong with the question.

Comment: Completely agree with @abelenky. There are many things wrong with this question.

Answer (score 6):

- Create the file.
- Write bytes to it, until you've written the size you want.
- Close file.

The loop should be all of about 2 lines of code.
What difficulties are you encountering?

Comment: I propose saving a part of diskspace-time-continuum by creating a sparse file.

Comment: My ESP tells me @user1069611 is not sufficiently advanced for sparse files yet.   I'm answering the question at the level he asked it. :)

Comment: @abelenky, hopefully StackOverflow is not a site where answers could be read only by the OP of the question. So including this information could be useful to the community.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, that's why we have two answers ;-)

Answer (score 0):

- create the file
- seek to the desired size
- write 0 bytes
- close the file.